# reference difference between 'in range()' usage and 'element in elements' usage within for loop in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, reference

I'm currently reading a dummy.txt, the content showing as below:

```
8t1080 0.077500 0.092123 -0.079937
63mh9j 0.327872 -0.074191 -0.014623
63l2o3 0.504010 0.356935 -0.275896
64c97u 0.107409 0.021140 -0.000909
```

Now, I am reading it using python like below:

```
lines = open("dummy.txt", "r").readlines()
```

I wanted to make a structure so that I can have a list... or array (doesn't matter) of arrays. Each smaller array will have the 0th element as string, and the following decimals will be a float. In order to do that, I'm currently trying:

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    for x in range(1, len(line)):
        line[x] = float(line[x])
```

Interestingly, this doesn't work, since

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
```

wouldn't actually split the line, and change the read data (lines variable, to be specific).

Meanwhile, below works, and successfully modifies the read data (lines variable).

```
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    lines[x] = lines[x].split()
    for x in range(1, len(line)):
        line[x] = float(line[x])
```

So what is the difference between the two for loop that has two different results?

Answer (score 1):

You would greatly benefit from [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) in this case:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dummy.txt', sep=' ', header=None)

>>> df.values

array([['8t1080', 0.0775, 0.092123, -0.079937],
       ['63mh9j', 0.327872, -0.074191, -0.014622999999999999],
       ['63l2o3', 0.5040100000000001, 0.356935, -0.27589600000000003],
       ['64c97u', 0.10740899999999999, 0.02114, -0.000909]], dtype=object)
```

Or all in one go (without saving it your text file as a dataframe object):

```
my_array = pd.read_csv('dummy.txt', sep=' ', header=None).values

>>> my_array
array([['8t1080', 0.0775, 0.092123, -0.079937],
       ['63mh9j', 0.327872, -0.074191, -0.014622999999999999],
       ['63l2o3', 0.5040100000000001, 0.356935, -0.27589600000000003],
       ['64c97u', 0.10740899999999999, 0.02114, -0.000909]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a data structure to output to for the first example i.e.

```
data = []
lines = open("dummy.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    for x in range(1, len(line)):
        line[x] = float(line[x])
    data.append(line)
```

The data list will contain what you want.

Comment: is it solved? if not, could you post the details of why for us to help?

Answer (score 0):

In your first case it IS working, however each time the for loops the line variable is reset to the next value, and its current value is lost to recieve the next one.

```
aux=[]
for line in lines: #here the program changes the value of line
    line = line.split() # here you change the value of line
    for x in range(1, len(line)):
        line[x] = float(line[x])
    aux.append(line)
```

using an auxiliar var you can "save" your values to later use

Comment: Even if the value of 'line' is reset to the next 'line', when I do 'line = line.split()', shouldn't it update the value within that 'line' within the 'lines', since 'line' is a reference to the memory? I'm still not quite sure with the behavior here.
It seems like the update is not happening at all.

Comment: I believe that the line var that recieves all the items from lines is temporary, it is meant to hold a value for you to use, and then forget it in the next iteration. For instance, if you try to acces the "line" var outside the for loop, it will raise a "no reference to... " Exception

Comment: about the split command, it really updates the variable, but then it forgets everything to start the loop again

Comment: Just clarify the line var merely copies the value of an element of the list on each loop but does not act as a reference to the element, if you want to edit the values of the lines list you need to use the indexing system you used in the working example, as lines[i] returns a reference to the element rather than the value of the element.